# Obtain Nreal (Xreal) Air 3DOF tracking information

Tags: macos, augmented-reality, tracking, virtual-reality, nreal

Using Unix-based system (Mac) what would be the minimum code to obtain the head-tracking 3DOF information coming through an USB-C port from Nreal (nowadays Xreal) Air virtual glasses? I would like to prefer shell commands or scripts, because Unity-based or similar approaches would be too complicated for my plans.

Comment: The [downloads page](https://developer.xreal.com/download) only links to the Unity SDK. The [documentation](https://xreal.gitbook.io/nrsdk/nrsdk-fundamentals/core-features) hints at an NRSDK that sites on a layer that *could be* native (e.g. Android NDK C++ library + Java JNI bindings maybe?), but there is not something available on their downloads page, not [github](https://github.com/orgs/nreal-ai/repositories). You can reach out to them directly for a special arrangement to get data via NDK c++ or Android SDK directly (non-Unity option) if they offer it. I doubt there's `adb shell` support.

Comment: To clarify I don't expect example code and an officially supported method of getting the pose data directly through `adb shell` (I could be wrong, but at best it might be some log messages you can manually parse if you're lucky and this is a very hacky option to begin with). It might be worth checking if the [WebXR plugin and samples](https://github.com/nreal-ai/webxr-samples/blob/main/ar-barebones.html#L141C13-L141C13) they offer gets you the pose data you need. (Hopefully tou can either use that directly in a WebGL view or forward the data via websockets to something else). Good luck